# lua Hashtables, table index is nil?

Tags: lua, hashtable, null, lua-table

What I'm currently trying to do is make a table of email addresses (as keys) that hold person_records (as values). Where the person_record holds 6 or so things in it. The problem I'm getting is that when I  try to assign the email address as a key to a table it complains and says table index is nil... This is what I have so far:

```
random_record = split(line, ",")
person_record = {first_name = random_record[1], last_name = random_record[2], email_address = random_record[3], street_address = random_record[4], city = random_record[5], state = random_record[6]}
email_table[person_record.email_address] = person_record
```

I wrote my own split function that basically takes a line of input and pulls out the 6 comma seperated values and stores them in a table (random_record)

I get an error when I try to say email_table[person_record.email_address] = person_record. 
But when I print out person_record.email_address it's NOT nil, it prints out the string I stored in it.. I'm so confused.

```
function split(str, pat)
   local t = {}  -- NOTE: use {n = 0} in Lua-5.0
   local fpat = "(.-)" .. pat
   local last_end = 1
   local s, e, cap = str:find(fpat, 1)
   while s do
      if s ~= 1 or cap ~= "" then
     table.insert(t,cap)
      end
      last_end = e+1
      s, e, cap = str:find(fpat, last_end)
   end
   if last_end <= #str then
      cap = str:sub(last_end)
      table.insert(t, cap)
   end
   return t
end
```

Comment: Could you post the exact error message you get?

Comment: Unfortunately that is the exact error message :(
"Table index is nil"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is copy and pasted from your example and runs just fine:

```
email_table = {}
random_record = {"first", "second", "third"}
person_record = {first_name = random_record[1], last_name = random_record[1], email_address = random_record[1]}
email_table[person_record.email_address] = person_record
```

So your problem is in your `split` function.

BTW, Lua doesn't have "hashtables". It simply has "tables" which store key/value pairs. Whether these happen to use hashes or not is an implementation detail.

Comment: Ah. ok.. my professor said lua only had hashtables but I disagreed :p.
Well all I've done to email_table was initialize it via email_table = {}

Then after that I assign it the above code.. I know it's not nil because I can say things like email_table["HAHA"] = person_record and it works. I just don't get why it won't allow person_record.email_address...

Comment: thats so weird...Well thanks! :) I have so many questions about lua since I'm just starting out. I'll probably be back :D

Comment: out of curiousity nicol, can u tell me why my split won't work? It basically splits a line up based on a delimeter and then stores the values into a table. I've added the code for my split function

Comment: @cj1098: That's a different question, which you should ask with the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you iterating over some lines that have comma-separated data.
Looking at your split function, it stops as soon as there's no more separator (,) symbols in particular line to find. So feeding it anything with less than 3 ,-separated fields (for **very common example**: an empty line at end of file) will produce a table that doesn't go up to [3]. Addressing any empty table value will return you a nil, so person_record.email_address will be set to nil as well on the 2nd line of your code. Then, when you attempt to use this nil stored in person_record.email_address as an index to email_table in 3rd line, you will get the exact error you've mentioned.